# AttributeError: Result object has no attribute save (when trying to save output in separate directory)?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to convert more than 100 ascii files to raster using python code. All the lines (**except Last two**) in my code presented below is successfully converting Ascii to tif format in the working directory. However, I want to save the new TIF files in a separate directory. Therefore, the last two lines in my code, I am trying to save in a new directory. But, I am getting an error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Subhasis\Project-Biological_monitoring\R_SAGA\Raster_data\ASCII_Raster.py", line 22, in <module>
    Ascii_raster.save(outname)
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'save'"
```

Code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set work environment
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/R_SAGA/Raster_data"

outWorkspace="C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/R_SAGA/Raster_data/Final"

dataType="INTEGER"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.asc"):
    outputraster = file.strip(".asc")+ ".tif"
    Ascii_raster=arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(file,outputraster,dataType)
    outname=os.path.join(outWorkspace,outputraster)
    Ascii_raster.save(outname)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem with "ExtractByMask" even though the syntax is exactly like that in the code sample from the help documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, I think you should change:

```
Ascii_raster=arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(file,outputraster,dataType)
outname=os.path.join(outWorkspace,outputraster)
Ascii_raster.save(outname)
```

to:

```
outname=os.path.join(outWorkspace,outputraster)
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(file,outname,dataType)
```

You are seeing your error in the original code because `Ascii_raster` is set to a result object and that does not have a `save` method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed the code the way you told me in your answer. It is creating the TIF files in the current working directory, However, I want to save the new TIF files in a separate directory.

Comment: The code I provided should be saving into `outWorkspace` i.e. "C:/Subhasis/Project-Biological_monitoring/R_SAGA/Raster_data/Final"

Comment: ASCIIToRaster_conversion doesn't create a Raster object, it creates a file, in a similar manner to Clip_analysis, CopyFeatures_management etc.. if you want it to be a raster you'll need to open it Ascii_raster=arcpy.Raster(outname) but that sort of defeats the purpose of trying to save it because *it's already there*.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Sorry to bother you again. Yes, I tried the code you told me and got this error below:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Subhasis\Project-Biological_monitoring\R_SAGA\Raster_data\ASCII_Raster.py", line 21, in <module>
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(file,outname,dataType)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2217, in ASCIIToRaster
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 010158: Unable to open file AN0008~1.ASC.
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (ASCIIToRaster).

Comment: I think you should research/ask that separately. It looks like the type of error you might see running the tool from its dialog i.e. not an ArcPy problem.